# Ionic 5 Firebase notification - this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe() never fired

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add notification with firebase in my ionic application (ionic 5). I follow this tutorial : https://www.positronx.io/ionic-firebase-fcm-push-notification-tutorial-with-example/

I recieve the token and when i send a notification from firebase console, the notification is displayed on the phone (emulator) but nothing is displayed in the console to handle the notification click...

I add FCM into provides in app.modules.ts and i have added the following code in the app.component.ts

```
import { FCM } from "@ionic-native/fcm/ngx";

...
constructor(
...
    private fcm: FCM
  ) {}

 initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();

      this.splashScreen.hide();
    this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
      console.log(token);
    });
    this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
      console.log(token);
    });

    this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        console.log('Received in background');
      } else {
        console.log('Received in foreground');
      }
    });

     if (token === null) {
      this.msgService.presentToast(
        "Impossible de configurer la reception des notifications"
      );
    }
    // Observer.hasTokenFCM.next(token);

    if (this.platform.is("ios") || this.platform.is("android")) {
      // this.saveToken(token);
    }
  });
```

And a have installed the following plugins:
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm

cordova plugin list:
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 4.4.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"

In my package.json:

dependencies:
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.22.0",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^4.1.1",

"cordova" -> "plugins": 
   "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "FCM_CORE_VERSION": "16.0.8",
        "FCM_VERSION": "18.0.0",
        "GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "2.3.+",
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "3.0.0"
      },

Thanks a lot if you found why the "this.fcm.onNotification.subscribe" is never fired...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, use [cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) plugin instead of [@ionic-native/fcm/ngx](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm), they are conflicting with each other. If [onNotification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated#fcmonnotification) method is not fired and you can't get the payload, try to use [getInitialPushPayload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated#fcmgetinitialpushpayload)

```
...
const pushPayload = await this.fcm.getInitialPushPayload();

if (pushPayload) {
  this.processPayload(pushPayload);
}

this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(
  (payload: PushNotification) => this.processPayload(payload)
);
...
```

Comment: Excuse me, did you find out how to fix it on iOS already? Thank you!

Comment: @M.Mariscal For me it works for Android and iOS platforms, so I think you can try it as it is without any changes.

Answer (score -1):

apparently i need to use

```
this.firebase.onMessageReceived().subscribe(notification => {
 if (notification["tap"]) {
...
}
....
});
```

with firebase plugin to handle notification... but i don't know why.

Comment: I have similar issue, could you kindly direct me how you solved it?